# php cli not working in my web server

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I am trying to run a php file in my web server in command line using

```
php test.php
```

But it is not working. it runs forever and takes 100% resources.
It was working yesterday and now it is not working.

I tried to debug the process using

```
strace -p <pid>
```

and got lots of

```
times(NULL) = -2058427839
```

Can anyone help me to debug this? Rebooting and upgrading is my last resort. Please suggest a solution without reboot or upgrade.

Comment: The source code of your test.php would be quite interesting to look at.

Comment: `php -v` tells you something like `PHP x.y.z (**cli**)`, not **cgi** or something like that?

Comment: you should also provide source code of that file to examine..

Comment: I just used <?php echo "test"; ?>. Also I tried php -v. It is also taking long time and 100% cpu and not returning to prompt. I had to use ctrl-c to exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run your php file in cli without the configuration file using the following command:

```
php -n <your-filename.php>
```

and then check whether its working?

Comment: Thank you Very much Ashok. When I run php without configuration file, it runs. There seems to be a problem in the extensions directory in php.ini. I changed the extensions directory and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Place this into your test.php file to check that it is working and to see what is available.

phpinfo();

Comment: in this case there's no difference what WONT be echoed - php info or just 'test'